# Drained and undrained shear strength of clay correlated?

Tags: geotechnical-engineering, soil-mechanics

When we measure the undrained strength of clay via CPT or triaxial test for instance, is there a way to correlate this to drained strength? How? I ask because measuring drained strength takes very long time but undrained strength can be measured quickly

Answer (score 2):

They are certainly correlated but there is no simple relationship. A commonly used rule of thumb, where I live, is $c'=0.1c_u$ for overconsolidated clays and zero otherwise, but reality is much more complex. See for example [this article](https://www.geo.dk/media/1209/correlation-between-drained-shear-strength-and-plasticity-index-of-undisturbed-overconsolidated-clays_final-after-1-review_b_sorensen-okkels.pdf). To the best of my knowledge, no accurate and generic relationship has been found.